# javascript/angularjs concatenate String with number for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var number = 0;  
var date = "2016-05-10"
$scope.test = date;
```

I would like to make a loop with the variable number in order to get as result

```
$scope.test1 = 2016-05-10
$scope.test2 = 2016-05-10
$scope.test3 = 2016-05-10
```

variable `$scope.test` is not an array but a string

Comment: Why _don't_ you have an array for `$scope.test?`. That's really the core of what it's for, having a series of related values.

Comment: I think you have to add more explanation to your question.

Comment: @Harris Weinstein   I'm  trying to embed multiple chart with a directive in angular. I can display one chart  like that  $scope.data = {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July']   (short example) .......              and  In my html page i get it with :         chart-data="data".  I would like to make a loop to get something like $scope.data1 =..... and display it  in html with  ng-repeat directive " chart-data=data1......(Note that "1" will be replace by increment variable.   If i do :   chart-data=data[1], it doesn't work. That's why i cant use array

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfmhcab3/4/)  It's a jsfiddle link to understand better  what i'm talking about. The fact is that i really want to embed many charts with one directive then I will create <canvas> element with ng-repeat directive to display the charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're undervaluing or ignorant of the purposes of arrays and `ng-repeat`. From your comments, it sounds like you want to be able to iterate through multiple groups of data sets, each group producing a chart, and I'm going to use your earlier comment as a permit to solve what I think is your *problem*, rather than your literal question.

Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x03quuru/) I made, a simple modification of your own JSFiddle sample. All I'm doing is placing the objects that contain the data sets (I copied and tweaked the one you had) into an array, then iterating over them, passing the data to charts with `ng-repeat` (you may need to scroll down in the view pane to see the second chart).

In your JS controller:

```
// Chart.js Data
    $scope.chartDataArray = [{
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My First dataset',
          // ... All the stuff for coloration
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
          label: 'My Second dataset',
          // ... All the stuff for coloration
          data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
      ]
    },{
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My First dataset',
          // ... All the stuff for coloration
          data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        {
          label: 'My Second dataset',
          // ... All the stuff for coloration
          data: [12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
        }
      ]
    }];
```

In your HTML view:

```
<canvas ng-repeat="data in chartDataArray" tc-chartjs-line chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend ng-click="chartClick($event)" chart="chart"></canvas>
```

This is basically just a foreach loop.

Comment: nice :) thank you. One more question about <canvas> element, By making this            " <canvas ng-repeat="data in chartDataArray" tc-chartjs-line chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend ng-click="chartClick($event)" chart="chart"></canvas>
" how can you display each chart in his own  <div>  ? It would be interesting to display each chart separately in a panel by example

Comment: The `ng-repeat` directive here is only relying on `$scope`, so it'd be valid on basically any HTML element that you want to repeat, and the `data` variable from each iteration will be valid anywhere within the repeating element. You can just cut and paste `ng-repeat` onto a div, put the canvas (remember to remove `ng-repeat` from _that_) within the div, and it'll do what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, it works! thank you very much. To go further, if you don't know the number of ChartData in the chartDataArray and you have to create a loop to handle datas, how would you create the loop to insert dynamically chartData in chartDataArray ?

Comment: I got it thank you. What i have done is : using a variable i=0 that I increment after drawing each chartDataArray[i]

Comment: I'm not totally sure I follow what you mean. As far as I can see, you shouldn't have to directly track anything. Could you respond with a version of the JSFiddle that shows what you've done?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really mastered jsfiddle. I will post what i'm talking about

Comment: last question , I have a problem : charts appears only on hover in my programm but works greats when I try it in jsfiddle without my datas. How  display it permanently ?

Comment: If the chart only appears when you hover, it probably means there's something actively hiding it when you don't hover. I can't diagnose the problem without seeing it, though. It may be best if you just post another question, since it is indeed a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.number; ++i) {
    $scope['test' + i] = date;
}
```

Like that?

Comment: thank you but I tried, it doesn't work.  I think when you bind with the scope in angular, you need the  $scope'.'

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.chartDataArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)// I replace "4" by variable which represent number of charts I need, I'm consuming Rest Api  
 {
  $scope.chartDataArray[i] = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],// I replace it by my datas
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
      strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
      pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] // my datas
    }, {
      label: 'My Second dataset',
      fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
      strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
      pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
      pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
      pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
      data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90] // my datas
    }]
  }; 
//scope.options ....
} //close the for
```

and in my html

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in chartDataArray">
  <canvas tc-chartjs-line chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-         legend ng-click="chartClick($event)" chart="chart"></canvas>
 </div>
```